# db2 UDB count(*) returns 0 from the view, but select * returns valid data

Tags: count, db2

I have encountered a strange situation in DB2 UDB V11.

When I run `SELECT COUNT(*)` FROM *view_name* it returns 0 rows.

However, when I run `SELECT * FROM *view_name*` the data is returned properly.

I have tried dropping and re-creating the view and ran REORG and RUNSTAT on the underlying table.

Have anyone seen this situation before?

Comment: This may happen due to non-enforced or/and violated constraints and different access plans. Show them both and DDL of participating objects.

Comment: I've seen this when at least one object referenced by the view  was a nickname, the query used host-variables, and predicate-pushdown was not properly configured.

Comment: Hi Graham, the view has several case statements to mask the sensitive data and is based on 2 joined tables. The are only 2 predicates and WHERE condition is very simple so not entirely sure this is what causing the problem. Also, the problem only exists in TEST environment, QA works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before when a MQT was involved. Because the optimizer will use the best way to query and can rewrite it to use the MQT this situation could happen when the MQT has not been refreshed but the table itsef has been updated/deleted already.

So check if any MQTs are involved.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your reply. You are absolutely correct, the underlying table this view is based on defined as MQT (ORGANIZE BY clause is present in the DDL) and it has been dropped and re-created and loaded with data recently. The underlying table contains data but view as I have mentioned earlier does not return anything but 0 when select count(*) is executed against it. However, SELECT * does return the data properly. Any suggestion how to refresh the MQT definition so the count(*) on the view would work properly?

Comment: Check out the refresh table statement here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000977.html - and do not forget to mark it as answer please